# FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory in production

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

In production most of the times from last week I am getting `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`.

I tried to increase the HEAP size but it didn't work. As it occurs in production so cant keep playing with it, it got down for a while. I am using Vuejs and .less in a Laravel Application.

My scripts in package.json looks like:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run watch",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --watch-poll --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
```

NPM version is `4.6.1`
NODE version is `8.16`

I am not getting this error in development but i tried with some of the solutions in development and production.

I tried adding a npm package

```
`npm install -g increase-memory-limit`
```

and then

```
`increase-memory-limit`
```

but the when i executed `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`, the modules didn't compile. The process got stuck for a long time and nothing happened.

Also i tried in production adding the below script:
    
      `"scripts": {
         "fix-memory-limit": "cross-env LIMIT=2048 increase-memory-limit"
       },
      "devDependencies": {
        "increase-memory-limit": "^1.0.3",
        "cross-env": "^5.0.5"
      }`

But it didn't worked too. The packages got broken, finally had to remove the code.

[The source is here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit)

I also tried with following script in dev:

```
"dev": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--max-old-space-size=4096\" NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
```

I didn't get any error but i am not not sure if it will work in production. Is this the correct approach to do it ?

or something like this:

```
npm run dev NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4096"
```

Cannot take more chances in production, got 2, 3 failures already.

Can someone advise a better approach and how can i check if the HEAP size increased or not.

Comment: This happened to me once and an outdated package was to blame. Are all of your packages up to date?

Answer (score -2):

I have same problem,
I solve by figure out,must have `<div>` after `<template>` in vue file

Comment: This should be a comment instead of answer. 
Please read this doc on how to write a nice answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer